# Video can't be opened after use colorchannelmixer in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to add effect to a video, and tried the following commands, does't work.

```
ffmpeg -i ./a.mp4  -filter_complex "colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131" -y  out.mp4

ffmpeg -i ./a.mp4  -vf colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131  -y out.mp4
```

Actually, the out.mp4 can be generated, but can't open.  "The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player."

Please tell me if my command is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i ./a.mp4 -vf colorchannelmixer={...} -pix_fmt yuv420p -y out.mp4
```

The ccm filter outputs RGB pixels which is automatically converted to yuv444p for x264 encoding. However, that pixel format  is incompatible with most players, so we need to force to a compatible format which is yuv420p.